# Polymer 1.0: I need a working example of <google-signin-aware>

Tags: authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-web-component

**Question:**

> **Can someone please provide a working code example of how to use `<google-signin-aware>`?**

---

I have a custom `<paper-button>` I'm trying to make a login button for Google.

[Here is the user documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin?active=google-signin-aware).

[Here is the Github repository](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best example for using `google-signin-aware` is the [`google-signin` element](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/blob/master/google-signin.html) itself.

Essentially what you have to do is to include `google-signin-aware` with the required attributes and then call the `signIn` method on this element.

```
<google-signin-aware
    id="aware"
    client-id="..."
    scopes="..."
    ...
    is-authorized="{{isAuthorized}}"
></google-signin-aware>

<paper-button on-tap="_signIn">Sign In</paper-button>


 _signIn: function () {
   this.$.aware.signIn();
 }
```

Comment: [Here is a follow on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632661/polymer-1-0-what-could-be-causing-this-error-uncaught-typeerror-this-is-not). Just ripe for a quick answer acceptance and upvote if you have any ideas. =]