# Polymer 1.0: What could be causing this error? "Uncaught TypeError: this is not a function"

Tags: authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0

#### Question

> **What could be causing the following console error?**
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: this.$.authgoogle.signin is not a function`

---

#### Goals

1. I am trying to implement a user authentication in my custom element.
2. I am using Google's authentication services to handle the authentication.
3. For styling purposes, I am using my own custom `<paper-button>` instead of the button that comes with, say, the `<google-signin>` element.
4. I am using the `<google-signin-aware>` element to do the authentication. [Here is the documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin?view=docs&active=google-signin-aware). [Here is the Github](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/blob/master/google-signin-aware.html).

---

#### Assumptions

1. I can not change the styling of the display button that comes with the `<google-signin>` element to sufficiently meet my UX design objective.
2. Therefore, I must use the `<google-signin-aware>` non-display element to handle the user authentication task.
3. The `<google-signin-aware>` is capable of handling the authentication task when used this way. I.e., independently of the `<google-signin>` element.

---

#### Code

```
<dom-module id="my-auth">
  <template>
    <google-signin-aware id="authgoogle"></google-signin-aware>
    <paper-button on-tap="_handleAuth">Login with Google</paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-auth',
      _handleAuth: function(e) {
        this.$.authgoogle.signin();
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't you use signIn() method not login. this.$.authgoogle.signIn()

Comment: @jimidough10: Nice catch! I made the corrective edits in my question and my code. Unfortunately, I still get exactly the same problem. Hm. Perhaps that's a clue? Ironically.

Comment: camelCase signin to signIn maybe?

Comment: @jimidough10: That worked. You nailed it. You rock! Thanks!

Comment: @jimidough10: Since you posted in the comments, I couldn't accept or upvote your help on my own question. So I looked up some of your other posts and upvoted a few I thought were particularly helpful. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the rep. I didn't feel like it was a proper answer. More of a nudge in the right direction so i put it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function call syntax is `.signIn()`.

First, I used `.login()`. Then I used `.signin()` (without the camelCase).

A cautionary tale: A second pair of eyes is always handy.